# Eror 405 (Method Not Allowed) when POST request to Giphy API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to POST a gif I recorded from my webcam to the Giphy API, but I keep getting this error:

> "net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

```
fetch(`upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs?api_key=${apiKey}&file=${data}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/gif' 
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.ok){
      return res.json()
    }else{
      console.log("Denied")
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error " + error)
  })
```

Comment: You forgot the `https://` or `http://` at the front of the URL.

Comment: Why are you setting the content type to `image/gif` but setting the body to the output of `JSON.stringify`?!

Comment: Shoud I set the body to data? I tried that and adding the https://  but then I get some sort of CORS policy error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068

Comment: @OrnellaAcerbi Are you make this upload API call from front end directly or is this code from a server (Node.js for example)?